# Which method is better to add "www." before domain name

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting, cname

I have search through Google and found 2 methods to add `www` before domain name. First is by adding a CNAME and second is using rewrite mod in *.htaccess* file.

I just want to know which method is better to use or there is other method because I'm currently using standalone WordPress as my back end.

Comment: Adding a CNAME will not create a redirection from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`. Anyway, the .htaccess method is usually fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need both - the CNAME is a DNS record that points `www.example.com` to `example.com`'s server so that if a browser tries to open `www.example.com` then it can find what server (IP address) it is stored on. The second is a rule on the server that says "if someone loads `example.com`, tell them that they should have loaded `www.example.com`"

Answer (score 1):

not only with CNAME records, but also you can put *.htaccess* code for redirection:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a 301 redirect (which is permanent redirect.)  After a few weeks the site will be visible with `www` in Google Search from that time.

Comment: The question is possibly a bit ambiguous, as it doesn't specifically mention redirects, but anyway... as mentioned in the other answer, you still need a CNAME record as otherwise the `www` subdomain won't be available. Although this is a bit academic as it is nearly always setup automatically as part of the hosting account setup.